# jquery one page scroll start at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the One Page Scroll jquery plugin (https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) and I want to have the site start from the bottom.

I have five sections, so when I added:

```
   $( window ).load(function() { $(".main").moveTo(5); })
```

The page loads at the top and then immediately scrolls down to the bottom. I'm trying to avoid that: just want it to load at the bottom and then the user can navigate upwards.

I'm still learning jquery/javascript so I have a feeling this is a simple fix and thats why I couldn't find an answer in the forum.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

[**Edit:** here's the working example](http://www.adelsonstrategies.com/demo/AdelsonStrategies.html)

Comment: I would probably try .moveTo(4) to make sure it is not 0-based indexing.

Comment: Also, have you initialized the plugin?
like use 
$(".main").onepage_scroll(); 
before 
$(".main").moveTo(5);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be very difficult for two reasons:

1. The browser constructs the DOM from top to bottom, like stacking blocks upside down. Handlers on `window.onload` or `$(document).ready` don't run until after the page has already been built and rendered. Any delay while your scripts and content are loading will exacerbate the lag time. To affect how it looks from the very beginning, your code would need to run even before `window.onload`. (EDIT: You can do that with JS that's outside an event handler and physically before the elements you're rendering, but it will run before those elements exist. Among other problems, you won't know how tall anything is yet.)
2. Before the DOM is rendered, there *is* no bottom of the page. It gains height as more blocks are stacked. You can add some kind of wrapper with an absolute height, but that has its own issues.

If you *really* want this to work smoothly, you may need a more radical approach. I suggest you **exclude the first page from the initial response, then add it dynamically afterward.** You can give it an inline `style="display:none"` or just add it later via AJAX. Injecting content at the top will push everything else down, so you'll need to automatically scroll down as the page expands upward. If you do it right, the user should never be able to tell.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach to me + clear explanation of why this is not so easy.

Comment: Thanks for this breakdown. I'll do a bit more research and see if this is something I'm able to accomplish. I appreciate it.

Comment: It's quite easy to do it using [fullPage.js plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) instead. Just use the `active` class in the section you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".main").moveTo(5);
});
```

".ready()" will wait for the DOM to load and then execute the script within

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I put this code in but it still starts at the top and then scrolls down to the end though.

Comment: I believe it's because of 'ease' animation. You can try to set 'animationTime: 0' to check if it will work but not sure if you will be able to change it back to 1000

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make us of fullPage.js instead and make use of the 'active' class to determine which section will be visible on load as detailed [in its docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#required-html-structure):

> Each section will be defined with a div containing the section class. The active section by default will be the first section, which is taken as the home page.
>
> ...
>
> If you want to define a different starting point rather than the first section or the first slide of a section, just add the class active to the section and slide you want to load first.

[Living demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/417/)

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="demo">Demo</div>Two</div>
        <div class="slide">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section active">Third</div>           <!-- Active section -->
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```